# Can not install OpenOffice on Windows 8.1 64 bit

Tags: windows-8, java, openoffice

Downloded Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Win_x86_install_en-US.exe
Right click Run as administrator

But got

[image]

Any ideas what to do?

Read, that at first need to instal java. Tried to install java Version 8 Update 31, but

[image]

Please, advice what need to do to instal OpenOffice

Comment: Most likely an incomplete download of the installation files; try downloading again and compare files to check. BTW, the similar LibreOffice (a fork of the original Open Office project), might work for you; see http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/. LibreOffice is working to remove any dependency on Java; it can be installed without it and is running that way on my PC's.

Comment: Yes, i installed LibreOffice, but it does not do what i need. OpenOffice was necessary to open text file with Calc and use `|||` as column delimiter. Tried with Excel and can not use `|||` as column delimiter; can use only `|`. So at the moment the only solution i found is use `|` as column delimiter, like `Column1 | Column2 | Column 3`

Comment: Or search-and-replace text for triple-pipe to single, ||| ->|